# Entity Framework in MVC 3: How to insert a model with a Foreign Key?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, insert, foreign-key-relationship

I have a Product Model, which contains a foreign key to a ProductCategory record, and looks like this.

```
public class ProductModel : IProductModel
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductImagePath { get; set; }
    public decimal? PricePerMonth { get; set; }
    public bool ProductActive { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, every time a new Product is created, a new ProductCategory is also created with all of it's values in the database being set to NULL, except for the ProductCategoryID field, which is auto generated.

In my Create view, I have a form, which contains a drop list populated with ProductCategories. Once the form is submitted, Create(Product product) Action is being called, and the new Product is being created. At this point, the new ProductCategory is also created, which is behavior that I don't want.

My Create(Product product) Action looks like this:

```
    //
    // POST: /Product/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        int productCategoryID = product.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID;
        product.ProductCategoryID = productCategoryID;
        _productService.InsertProduct(product);
    }
```

... and my InsertProduct methods looks like this ...

```
    public void InsertProduct(Product product)
    {
        Db.Products.AddObject(product);
        Save();
    }
```

Why is this code causing a new ProductCategory to be created every time?

EDIT: Adding table definition, in response to an answer given, whcih asked for more information:

```
TABLE Product (
ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
ProductCategoryID INT, -- FK to ProductCategory 
ProductName NVARCHAR(255),
ProductDescription NVARCHAR(MAX),
ProductImagePath NVARCHAR(1024),
PricePerMonth DECIMAL(7,2), -- ex 11111.11
ProductActive BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
)

TABLE ProductCategory (
ProductCategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
ProductCategoryName NVARCHAR(255),
ProductCategoryDescription NVARCHAR(MAX),
ProductCategoryActive BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
)
```

EDIT 2:

I still don't understand why, exactly, but I was able to work around this problem with the following changes made to my Create(Product product) Action:

```
var productCategoryID = product.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID;
product.ProductCategoryID = productCategoryID;
var newProduct = new Product
        {
            ProductName = product.ProductName,
            ProductDescription = product.ProductDescription,
            PricePerMonth = product.PricePerMonth,
            ProductImagePath = product.ProductImagePath,
            ProductCategoryID = productCategoryID
        };

_productService.InsertProduct(newProduct);
```

EDIT 3:

I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of this, but ... I have discovered that this problem has something to do with the ProductCategory member of the Product class. From what I can tell, ModelBinding is automatically populating that property with a new ProductCategory every time the form is submitted. I can consistently avoid the problem I've been having here by explicitly setting Product.ProductCategory = null;

Comment: this is more of an Entity Framework question (I assume that's what you're using here) than a MVC question

Comment: Okay, I'll change the title and tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious about your problem, so I got some pointers from a well-known author and trainer on MVC, and figured out the following. Key concepts are available in an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx).

The MVC model binding process binds the form data from the view to the model that you pass to the Create action. It finds the appropriate values in the form data to bind to the Product and ProductCategory objects, and carries out the model binding.

The problem in your case is that the Entity Framework is not aware of the objects, because you created Product and ProductCategory objects on their own, outside of the EF context, rather than entities from the EF context. In your case, you're using EF 4.1 with the DbContext, but this would also apply with different methods to EF 4.0 with the ObjectContext.

Your new Product object doesn't exist within your EF context or database --- you haven't added it yet --- but your ProductCategory does. You need to map the ProductCategory object hanging off your new Product object to an existing ProductCategory from your EF entities. To do that, you can either find the existing ProductCategory by looking it up by primary key (ProductCategoryId) then assigning it to your product.ProductCategory, or you can "attach" your free-floating ProductCategory object to your entities. You pass it your ProductCategory object, and it essentially does the same thing as finding an existing entity --- it looks up the entity by primary key. Both methods essentially take an existing ProductCategory object, tells the EF that your object is an entity, and sets the entity's "state" to "Unchanged", so when you call `context.SaveChanges()` it ignores the ProductCategory entity and therefore finds no changes to send back to the underlying database.

So, before you add your Product to the EF context, you first need to **A**) find an existing ProductCategory entity that is already attached to EF, **B**) attach the detached ProductCategory object, or **C**) set the product.ProductCategoryId and null out the product.ProductCategory reference so the EF will find the ProductCategory for you. You chose Option C.

**Option A** (Find an existing, attached entity):

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    // find an attached entity based on primary key
    var productCat = 
        Db.ProductCategories.Find(product.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId); 
    product.ProductCategoryId = productCat.ProductCategoryId;
    product.ProductCategory = productCat;
    _productService.InsertProduct(product);
}
```

**Option B** (Attach a detached entity):

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    // attach an entity - EF will find the entity to attach using the entity's primary key
    Db.ProductCategories.Attach(product.ProductCategory); 
    product.ProductCategoryId = product.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId;
    _productService.InsertProduct(product);
}
```

**Option C** (Null out the entity reference):

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    product.ProductCategoryId = product.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId;
    product.ProductCategory = null;
    _productService.InsertProduct(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nekno! I'm going to think about this some more, in order to really digest it. I'm also going to start digging further into EF, in order to learn it better. ... as a side note, why did you remove the name of the well-known author? I won't repeat the name out of respect for you and the author, but I saw it before you changed it and my curiosity was peeked.

Comment: @campbelt - I edited my answer a bit to add some explanation.  Also, if you saw the name, then that is what I wanted to accomplish, so you could look up his sites/books/videos to seek more info. I decided, however, that "name dropping", no matter how trivial, wouldn't lend credibility to the info, as I had hoped, but would possibly just look crass and therefore detract from the message. And, I didn't check with him first.

Answer (score 1):

Product Category has been created because you're setting ProductCategoryID for your NEW PRODUCT object.

and I wonder why you're setting product category in this way ? and where is this category id came from ?

anyway if you're using entity framework you have to make sure you have the RIGHT relationships in SQL server (for example One-to-One or One-to-Many). Some of unexpected behaviors in entity framework is related to bad database design in sql server.

anyway if that does not help you give me your exact table mapping and relationship and write more precise of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I added the table definitions to my original post. I hope that helps to clarify things. As for what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to create a new product that is assigned to a ProductCategory that already exists. I am not sure if that is what you were asking. Please let me know if it was not, and I REALLY appreciate you assistance. The ProductCategoryID is coming from a drop list of existing Product Categories, which I have added to my Product Create view.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Create` action, what is the value of `productCategoryID` after it is assigned? Is it the value selected from the drop-down list on the form, or is it a new value?

If you've defined a foreign-key relationship from the primary key in the ProductCategory table to a foreign key in the Product table, then every time you save a Product with a ProductCategoryID value, that ProductCategoryID value must exist in the ProductCategory table.

So if you're saving Products with ProductCategoryID values that don't exist in the ProductCategory table, the record must be inserted in the ProductCategory table in order to insert the record in the Product table.

Also, ordinarily your `Create` action should accept a `ProductModel` object from the `Create` view. That is your page data model, from which you extract the values needed to create a `Product` entity from your EF context ("entities" object), then save the `Product` entity.

I'm not quite sure about your `Product` vs `ProductModel` classes.

Comment: Thank you, nekno. The productCategoryID that is being retrieved from the drop list in the Create form is 1, which is a ProductCategoryID that DOES exist in the database. However, for some reason, even if I try to explicitly set the Product's ProductCategoryID Foreign Key value to this ID, it doesn't work. When the new Product is created, it seems to be ignoring the explicitly set value and is generating a new ProductCategory.

Comment: I just updated my original post again, saying that I was able to work around this problem by creating a new Product and then sending that into my InsertProduct method. Though, I admit I still don't understand why that had to be done ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the issue most likely is in the code where you create your dropdown.

In your controller, create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` of the ProductCategory table, and pass this to the ViewBag, e.g., `ViewBag.ProductCategories`.  Then, in your view, use the following for your dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductCategories)
```

Then, in your [HttpPost] Create controller action, ProductCategoryId will already be populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@campbelt: Not sure why it is happening.  This is how I did it.  I didn't pass my domain object to the view, but passed through a view model called `EditGrantApplicationViewModel`.  In my scenario I have a grant application form.  On this form the user can select a bank from a dropdown list.  Below is my partial view model containing the details for the bank dropdown.

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   // Other properties

   public int BankId { get; set; }
   public List<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
}
```

My view for this dropdown looks like this:

```
<td valign="top"><label>Bank:</label> <span class="red">*</span></td>
<td>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BankId, new SelectList(Model.Banks, "Id", "Name", Model.BankId), "-- Select --")<br>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BankId)
</td>
```

My Create action method:

```
public ActionResult Create(EditGrantApplicationViewModel viewModel)
{
   // Check input parameter

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      viewModel.Banks = bankService.GetAll();

      return View("Create", viewModel);
   }

   // Map from view model to domain object
   GrantApplication grantApplication = (GrantApplication)grantApplicationMapper.Map(viewModel, typeof(EditGrantApplicationViewModel), typeof(GrantApplication));

   // Insert to database
   grantApplicationService.Insert(grantApplication);

   return RedirectToRoute(Url.GrantApplicationIndex());
}
```

Partial GrantApplication object:

```
public class GrantApplication
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int BankId { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping will populate the BankId property in my GrantApplication object (which was selected) from the dropdown and this is what will be added to the column in my GrantApplication table.